# how to populate combo box using stored procedure oracle sql and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am just new in oracle and using procedure and still learning, but I have a problem how can I populate the combo box using store procedure? I already have a code but when I run it, it shows an error IndexOutOfRangedException was unhandled and Cannot find Column 1.

Here's my code
(Procedure/Oracle Sql:)

```
procedure cmbbox_location (o_output out o_refcur) 
as
    o_cur o_refcur;
begin
    open o_cur for
        select city_id, city_name from city;

    o_output := o_cur;
end cmbbox_location;
```

(program/vb.net)

```
Private Sub Main_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    instantiate_dev()
    ora_conn.Open()
    populate_cmbbox_loc()
End Sub

Private Sub populate_cmbbox_loc()
    instantiate_dev()
    ora_conn.Open()
    qr.populate_location()
    cmblocation.DataSource = dt
    cmblocation.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
    cmblocation.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(1).ColumnName
    cmblocation.Text = ""
    cmblocation.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Public Function populate_location()
    dt = New DataTable
    bg.GetProcDataTable(connStr, "Location_Package.cmbbox_location")
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("O_OUTPUT", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    adap_or.SelectCommand = cmd
    adap_or.Fill(dt)

    Return dt
    ora_conn.Close()
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know vb.net, but shouldn't `o_output out o_refcur` be `o_output out sys_refcursor`? `o_refcur` doesn't sound like a type, it sounds like an `OUT` parameter. Also you don't need `o_cur`, you can open `o_output` directly.

Comment: Are you using a Oracle Client or some other provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting indicates that you are indexing something that doesn't exist, it's possible/probable your stored procedure isn't returning anything.  To address William Robertson's concern about the ref cursor:

There are any number of ways to output a ref cursor.  The one I use the most is a ref cursor type defined in the package definition, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Location_Package IS

    TYPE DataOutCursor IS REF CURSOR;
    procedure cmbbox_location (o_output out DataOutCursor);

END Location_Package;
/
```

Then in the procedure in the package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Location_Package IS
    procedure cmbbox_location (o_output out DataOutCursor) as
    begin
        open o_output for
        select city_id, city_name from city;
    end;
END;
/
```

I assume the error is occurring here:

```
cmblocation.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
cmblocation.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(1).ColumnName
```

It is always best to make sure the data table has data first so wrap the combo box lines with:

```
IF dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    ' ..... assign the data table to the combo box
Else
    ' Some error message ...
End IF
```

This will get rid of the unhandled exception and help you to figure out the issue.

On last thing, your function needs to return a value (datatable):

```
Public Function populate_location() as Datatable
    dt = New DataTable
    bg.GetProcDataTable(connStr, "Location_Package.cmbbox_location")
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("O_OUTPUT", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    adap_or.SelectCommand = cmd
    adap_or.Fill(dt)

    Return dt
    ora_conn.Close()
End Function
```